# haproxy and certificates mismatch

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy

I have been wrestling with Haproxy for a few hours now and I am probably missing something in my limited know-how.

I have two servers (ha1.domain.com and ha2.domain.com), both with keepalived and haproxy, that should manage failover between two other servers (mail1.domain.com and mail2.domain.com). There is one VIP (domain mailserver.domain.com).

When I connect to the public domain via browser I get an error that the certificate could not be verified as the domain (mailserver.domain.com) doesn't match the domain in the certificate (either mail1.domain.com or mail2.domain.com). What is the best strategy to avoid this issue?

My haproxy config:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 debug
    maxconn   45000 # Total Max Connections.
    daemon
    nbproc      1 # Number of processing cores.

defaults
    timeout server 86400000
    timeout connect 86400000
    timeout client 86400000
    timeout queue   1000s

# [HTTP Site Configuration]
listen  http_web xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:80
    bind *:80
    #bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/iredmail.org/iredmail.org.pem
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/ha2.domain.com.pem
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    mode http
    balance roundrobin  # Load Balancing algorithm
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    cookie SRVNAME insert
    server mail1 bbb.ccc.ddd.eee:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 cookie SA check
    server mail2 bbb.ccc.fff.ggg:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 cookie SB check

# [HTTPS Site Configuration]
listen  https_web xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:443
    mode tcp
    balance source# Load Balancing algorithm
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    server mail1 bbb.ccc.ddd.eee:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
    server mail2 bbb.ccc.fff.ggg:443 weight 1 maxconn 512 check

# Reporting
listen stats
bind :9000
mode http

# Enable statistics
stats enable

# Hide HAPRoxy version, a necessity for any public-facing site
stats hide-version

# Show text in authentication popup
stats realm Authorization

# URI of the stats page: localhost:9000/haproxy_stats
stats uri /haproxy_stats

# Set a username and password
stats auth Username:Password
```

Thanks

Comment: `listen  a   b`   is bad syntax on typical versions of haproxy. What version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't intend to access the servers with the names `mail1.domain.com` or `mail2.domain.com`, the easiest is to get for both servers a certificate with the name `mailserver.domain.com`.

If you want to keep the servers accessible by their own names, get a certificate that has both names, the individual `mail1.domain.com` or `mail2.domain.com`, and the common `mailserver.domain.com`.